# collectionView.dequeueReusableCell not calling Cell's init

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, reloaddata

When a user touches a collection view cell, it expands to full screen. Then you click an x button and it shrinks back down into the collection view.

The problem is, I call `collectionView.reloadItems()` and it only calls the cells init function the first time. Every time after that it will call `cellForItem(at: )` which calls `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell()`, but it won't call the cell's init again which makes the stuff inside the cell not show up.

Make cell full screen and then press X to reloadItem and bring it back down to normal size in the collection view

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else { return }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [], animations: {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

            // make cell full screen
            cell.frame = collectionView.bounds
            cell.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(cell)

            //disable scroll
            collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

            // make overlay full screen
            cell.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

            // show X button
            cell.showXBtn()

            cell.xBtn.onTapped = {
                // enable scroll
                collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true

                // shrink back to collection view
                collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

                // hide x button
                cell.hideXBtn()

                // show navigation bar
                self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
            }
        }, completion: nil)     
    }
```

If I call cell.setup() here, the code works fine. If I try to call `cell.setup()` in the cell's init function (or didMoveToSuperview()), it only works the first time `collectinView.reloadItems()` is called.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        // setup cell. If I call it within the cell, it only works the first time I call collectionView.reloadItem()
        cell.setup()

        // ignore spelling error lol
        let image = UIImage(named: "bdyaFilter")!
        cell.imageView.image = image

        return cell
    }
```

My cell. The init is only called the first time I try to reload items

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let xBtn = XButton()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // this is only called the first time i call collectionView.reloadItems()
       // setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        addImageView()
        addXBtn()
        hideXBtn()
    }
    private func addImageView() {
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        self.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    func addXBtn() {
        xBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 30, height: 30)
        self.addSubview(xBtn)
    }    
    func hideXBtn() {
        xBtn.isHidden = true
    }  
    func showXBtn() {
        xBtn.isHidden = false
    } 

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierfor:)`. To recycle cell objects, rather than allocating and freeing a whole bunch of objects as a user scrolls.

You need to call `setup()` yourself, preferably from the `prepareForReuse()` method, and provide any new values the cell might need.

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its `init(frame:)` method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s `prepareForReuse()` method instead.

From [the documentation of `UICollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell)